# How to write tests to prevent Google Tag Manager logic from breaking?

Tags: angular, automated-tests, google-tag-manager

After I inject `UA-xxx-id` into my angular app running on `app.site.com`, I can use google tag manager to dynamically put together rules for things I want to track.

For example, I can look for anything with the CSS class style `blue` and tell google to track the total number of clicks. BUT if later some other developer updates the CSS such that the rule no longer matches then I'm in trouble.

Question: What sort of tests or test frameworks do you use to keep your sanity and write tests to avoid metric rules from breaking/disappearing?

One solution that comes to mind is writing protractor tests that validate that on said page/route, the rules I've added to google are still valid but I'm want to know what the community actually uses.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while it is a good question it invites open-ended discussion which is not really what SO is for.

Comment: Hi @pulkitsinghal currently I am in the same position. Have you have ever heard of nightwatch? for an example look at http://nightwatchjs.org/

Comment: @EikePierstorff - where should one go to seek advice from community? According to the FAQ, this is NOT a best practice question. I offer a concrete solution and ask for those used by others if any. If we don't collaborate on StackOverflow then where?